# Live() function not working with some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, live, jqtransform

I'm trying to bind some change events to a select element which has been previously been transformed by jqTransform (http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/).

As change() function does not work after this transformation, I've followed this [excellent advice](http://www.code-pal.com/the-select-problem-after-using-jqtransform-and-its-solution/) from Code-Pal. Then I'm trying to apply a click function with the live() event (as future forms will be called with Ajax).

So far I've got this, which does not work:

```
$("div#caracteristicas-form-wrap div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a").live('click', function(e) {
console.log("Testing");
});
```

Strangely, this DOES work:

```
$("div#caracteristicas-form-wrap div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a").bind('click', function(e) {
console.log("Testing");
});
```

And even this:

```
$("div#caracteristicas-form-wrap div.jqTransformSelectWrapper").live('click', function(e) {
console.log("Testing");
});
```

So it's not that jqTransform is still not loaded. For some reason, live() stops working as soon as I'm selecting elements from a list. Any idea of what could be happening?

This is the html code after the jqtransform:

```
<div class="jqTransformSelectWrapper" style="z-index: 10; width: 194px;">
  <div>
    <span style="width: 179px;">Tarjeta estándar</span>
    <a class="jqTransformSelectOpen" href="#"></a>
  </div>
  <ul style="width: 192px; display: none; visibility: visible; height: 125px; overflow: hidden;">
    <li>
      <a class="selected" index="0" href="#">Tarjeta estándar</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a index="1" href="#">Tarjetas cantos redondos</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a index="2" href="#">Tarjetas doble</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a index="3" href="#">Tarjeta PVC</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a index="4" href="#">Tarjeta adhesiva</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <select id="id-subproducto" class="jqTransformHidden" name="subproducto" style="">
    <option value="1">Tarjeta estándar</option>
    <option value="2">Tarjetas cantos redondos</option>
    <option value="3">Tarjetas doble</option>
    <option value="4">Tarjeta PVC</option>
    <option value="5">Tarjeta adhesiva</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the problem and giving all you anchor elements the same class and try using `live()` on them?

Comment: Why can't you just use bind then?

Comment: Im assuming its used via ajax loaded content otherwise he would, Hector obviously knows the difference...

Comment: Buf, i've tried to give the anchors a class ("hacking" jqtransform) and doing

    $("li.select-items a").live('click', function(e) {
      console.log("Testing");
    });

And nothing happens... it works with the bind event, though... It seems like live doesn't recognize the anchors. 

Now it's officially driving me crazy.

Comment: Not much more I can do to help, Only thing I can suggest if its possible could you set up a JSfiddle with everything required and reproduce the problem? You can include external library's (Such as jqtransform) so you should be able to set it up exactly as it is for you. Without being able to reproduce it its very hard to help you debug when you clearly atleast know what your doing so its not anything ridiculously easy or obvious.

Comment: Have you tried rearranging the selector? For example: $("div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a", "div#caracteristicas-form-wrap ") or $("ul li a", "div#caracteristicas-form-wrap  div.jqTransformSelectWrapper"), does that make any difference at all? (It shouldn't, but its worth trying!)

Comment: I think that I've found out where the problem is. JqTransform is causing the conflict with the "live" function. There's a click function that mess with my live event.

Still, I don't get why it is not messing with the bind function. I recommend you to run away from the jqTransform plugin, it's a dead-end project. Thanks everyone anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I dont have exactly the same selectors but it all seems to be working:

http://jsfiddle.net/HenryGarle/DeYH2/1/

```
$("div#caracteristicas-form-wrap div.jqTransformSelectWrapper ul li a").live('click', function(e) {
   alert("Testing");
});
```

**Edit:** Updated to use the same selectors

Comment: Yes, I see... ok, the only explanation is that some other function is causing some kind of conflict. But it is really bizarre how removing the "ul li a" solves the problem...

Comment: It may be caused by jqTransform, I've never personally used it. Try removing / moving the bits you want selected outside of something that has the jqTransform ran on it. See if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you're having trouble with jQuery `live` you might want to check out [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead.

Also have a look at [Why You Should Never Use jQuery Live](http://jupiterjs.com/news/why-you-should-never-use-jquery-live)

Comment: could this be a browser issue?  can you try your original code in a different browser, and also paste your `delegate` version somewhere?

Comment: I've tried with Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Nothing. I don't really get why i'm having differents results with "bind" and with "live".

Comment: $("div#caracteristicas-form-wrap div.jqTransformSelectWrapper p#producto-1 ul li.select-items").delegate('a', 'click', function(e) {});

Answer (score 0):

Well guys, after struggling with jqTransform for too many projects, I've switched to [UniformJS](http://uniformjs.com/). Working with it is easier, my life is nicer, the colors in the sky are brighter and girls smile et me when I'm walking down any street.

I recommend it.